# How to make iPhone and iPad version of an app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiview

I am trying to make an app which works on both iPhone and iPad. I am looking how to make an interface compatible on both. When the app loads I am displaying a table view. How can I load different nibs based on device? I am using this to switch between nibs.

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(userInterfaceIdiom)]) 
    {
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) 
        {
            device = @"iPad";
        }
        else 
        {
            device = @"iPhone";
        }

    }
```

But in MainWindow.xib it says view is loaded from the view controller for iPhone. Can I make this dynamic based on device? ie I want to show from the start of app different nibs based on device.
Thanks.

Answer (score 27):

Actually, Apple does all this automatically, just name your NIB files:

```
MyViewController~iphone.xib // iPhone
MyViewController~ipad.xib // iPad
```

and load your view controller with the smallest amount of code:

```
[[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; // Apple will take care of everything
```

Comment: NB: as someone posted to a mailing list recently ... be careful to get the case correct! Apple's special code is case sensitive - if you spell it "iPhone" or "iPad" you'll find this silently fails, with no explanation :(

Comment: @Adam this is not working for ios5. I tried with ios6 and for that it is working fine.any idea why not working?

Comment: Works fine for me in iOS 4 + 5 + 6. Double check case sensitivity of all files, and try a "Clean" before rebuilding. Also check you have 0 warnings.

Answer (score 6):

You can do that in a similar way:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
    mainMenu = [[MainMenu alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenuiPad" bundle:nil]; 
}else{  
    mainMenu = [[MainMenu alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenu" bundle:nil]; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I said when we open MainWindow.xib in interface builder it says 'view is loaded from the abc_iPhoneAppViewController' which is UI for iPhone. How can I change it to iPad one. Either in IB or through code. Could you please give a detailed example. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

For making universal app,

1-set target family in info build tab for app as iPhone/iPad.

2- Delete window from main window.

3- Add two xib one for iPhone and one for iPad(by selecting iPad xib).

4- make appDelegate class as controller file for these xib's.

5- Add window on these xibs and view controller or navigation controller and by IB Inspector set load nib name and controller file here which one is your first view.

6- And then make differnet xib for iPad and iPhone which having tableview or other controls.

7-Make single contoller file or different controler file for different device for same you need to check the device by this if else condition

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
```

8-Now you need to load xib in appDelegate class in method didFinishL--

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){

   // load your nib for iPad here which having view controler or navigation controller as well window.
}else{  
    //load nib for iPhone. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `Info.plist`:
Main nib file base name [`NSMainNibFile`]: MainWindow_iPhone
Main nib file base name (iPad) [`NSMainNibFile~ipad`]: MainWindow_iPad

I hope this helps you.