# How is an AppDelegate instanciated?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have an iOS application for which I want to create a ViewController programmatically.

I started an empty XCode project and modified the main method so it looks like this

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"MyAppDelegate_iPad");
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

The app is a Universal Application, `MyAppDelegate_iPad` is a subclass of `MyAppDelegate`, which is a subclass of `NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>`.

My problem is that the `applicationDidFinishLoading` method I've overridden in `MyAppDelegate_iPad` is never called (break point on the first line never hits).  The method looks like this

```
-(void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    if(!window)
    {
        [self release];
        return;
    }
    window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    rootController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];

    [window addSubview:rootController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [window layoutSubviews];
}
```

I removed the line to link to a nib file from my plist file (I used to get the default "My Universal app on iPad" white screen) and now all that is displayed is a black screen.  `applicationDidFinishLoading` is still not being called.

Am I doing something wrong?  How should I properly create my AppDelegate instance?

Comment: Assuming this is a sample, can you post it?

Comment: @Deepak It's not a sample.  I based myself on another SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809898 but otherwise it's the basic XCode empty project for Universal applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s a main nib file that bootstraps your application. This nib file is referenced in the Info.plist file under the  `NSMainNibFile` key and should contain an object that corresponds to your application delegate class (setting the *Class* attribute in Interface Builder). This application delegate object is referenced by the *delegate* outlet on the file’s owner placeholder.

So if I understand things correctly, the application loader loads the main nib file, setting itself as the nib owner. Its `delegate` property gets set to a fresh instance of your application delegate class, and so the loader knows where to dispatch the various application lifecycle event callbacks.

There’s an awesome blog post about Cocoa application startup on [Cocoa with Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/03/cocoa-application-startup.html).

Comment: I'm actually trying to do everything programmatically and not use nib files for my user interface.  Is that possible or do I neeed a nib regardless?

Comment: @pwny: You can always create a single bootstrapping nib that will only create your application delegate. From there on you can do everything in code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making universal you don't need two different app delegate classes. see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908563/how-to-make-iphone-and-ipad-version-of-an-app/4908756#4908756) (my answer), it may be help you to make universal app.

Comment: The Universal app template XCode creates for you has two different AppDelegates though.  Any reason why?