# Xcode 4.2 , change the iPhone xib to iPad xib

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xib

I have created the project which consists of 5 xibs. When I try to run the project in the iPad simulator . Some of the Xibs are coming in the iPhone screen size. I want to convert those iphone xibs which will support the iPad Xib screen size. Any idea how to do it ?

NOTE: I want to support both the iPhone and iPad

Comment: If you have created those .xib files targeted for iPhone then create a new view file targeted for iPad. And so on you can create separate .xib files for iPad.

Comment: You mean, create a xib under the same name for the ipad like iphone and I want to add the UI things again, like I have added for the iPhone ?

Comment: Exactly.. there you are..! create a new.xib with name postfix as `a-iPad.xib` & go on. The standard way to create universal app recommends this.

Comment: Even `Prasad G`'s answer would help u later in the project; to identify the .xib for iPhone & iPad and use them properly depending on the current device

Comment: Ya. I found that was useful. I have one doubt regarding that, In that code we are checking whether it is iphone or ipad and then we are loading the xib. But how come some xibs in my project is resized to ipad  eventhough I didnt check the condition and also I have created one xib.

Comment: Yes good question(+1to comment). Even this is wonder for me. Coz I was having iPhone app in store & then I started making it universal. In the development phase I found the same especially with some table views.

Comment: I guess this will be the reason. If you have checked the option Universal when creating the xib , it is switching automatically. If you are not creating as Universal , then we need to create two xib's .  Anyway thanks for the reply and for +1 comment.

Comment: ^ iOS automatically uses the XIBs whose postfix is "~ipad" for iPad. Notice the tilda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just copied the old Xib and renamed it as ~ipad at the last. And in the source code instead of 320*480 I have replaced the iPad resolution. And my UI i.e interface builder looks like the iPad and my application is detecting the ipad xib's . Thanks for every one.

Answer (score 18):

You can convert iPhone xib into iPad xib using following step.

> > Right click the file (in xcode) and Open As > Source Code
> >
> > The 2nd line should look like:

```
<archive type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="7.10">
Replace with:

<archive type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.iPad.XIB" version="7.10">
```

> > Search for "IBCocoaTouchFramework" and Replace all occurrences with "IBIPadFramework"
> >
> > Save the file and Open As > Interface Builder - iOS

you can do this for al xib...and you have your iPhone xib now in iPad xib.

Hope, this will help you..

Comment: Sorry that I didn't mention. I want to support both the iPhone and iPad . But I think this will support only the iPad

Comment: You can make first copy of iPhone and than apply above step so it will create new xib for iPad.

Comment: Let me clear. You are telling to copy the iPhone xib and rename to **** ~.ipad and then in the source code I should make the necessary changes in the xib as you have mentioned above. Am i right ?

Comment: I had the same problem, and thanks to Nit, it is now fixed and working like a champ... thank you so much for this snippet of info.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be helpful to you

```
 if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
            self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        } else {
            self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }
```

Comment: I am having only the iPhone xib, I don't have the xib for the iPad

Comment: When you create new project, you can use 'universal' in device family and don't click on 'use story board' then you will get iPad xib and also iPhone xib.  I think you you used only 'iPhone' in device family. Check it.

Comment: I have checked. The Target device Family is shown as iPhone/iPad

Comment: I use iOS 5.0 version and Xcode4.2. It shows 3 options those are universal,iPad and iPhone.

Comment: Ya. In the Target under the Summary tab, the Devices : Universal

Comment: No no no - don't do this! Use the Apple docs instead. Name your files with ~ipad or ~iphone. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9603894/153422

Answer (score 1):

Then you should create your project or update your project universal and change ipad xib setting and autoresize it.

Comment: You mean create the whole project again ? OMG. Now I can see in the project settings that Target Device Family as iPhone/iPad. Is there any other way to convert the iPhone xib ?

Comment: No there is no other way that will automatically convert all ***iPhone .xib*** to ***iPad .xib*** with satisfied views.

Comment: If you don't mind . Can you tell me how to update the settings. Only few xibs are not in proper size ,rest of them are correct. And I guess  my project support universal.

Comment: After update system automatically create ipad xib also then you can use that xib and di same like iPhone xib and then run on ipad its bummmmp and yo got your output nicely.

Answer (score 0):

it's worked for me:

Make a copy of the .xib in the Finder.
Open the copied file in a text editor.
Change "com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" to "com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.iPad.XIB".
Change all instances of "IBCocoaTouchFramework" to "IBIPadFramework".
Search for sizes like {480, 320} and edit them. Or just reopen the file in Xcode and use the GUI to resize items as needed.
This also works vise-versa, if you need to change an iPad xib into an iPhone xib.