# "touchesEnded" not recognizing entire view

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

I am trying to customize a calendar program (originally written for the iPhone) I found (http://code.google.com/p/iphonecal/) to work on the iPad. It was written using .xib files for the controller and the UIView.

For some reason, it does not "fire" *touchesEnded* anywhere on the right 2/3 of the entire view.  It works fine when using the iPhone simulator, but not the iPad simulator.

It was my understanding that *touchesEnded* monitors the entire view, but doesn't appear to be doing so in this case.

Any ideas of what could be causing this?

UPDATE:  it's back... I reset the simulator, did a clean, re-build and the problem is back.  Here is the code that doesn't even get touched by the right-hand side of the UIView:

```
//++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
//--  touchesEnded
//++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  {

    int width = self.frame.size.width;

    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    //UIView* theview=[self hitTest:touchPoint withEvent:event];

    if(touchPoint.x < 40 && touchPoint.y < headHeight)
        [self movePrevMonth];
    else if(touchPoint.x > width - 40 && touchPoint.y < headHeight)
        [self moveNextMonth];
    else if(touchPoint.y > headHeight)  
        [self touchAtDate:touchPoint];

}
```

Comment: Could you give us your code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem... both of the .xib files were not set up to use the iPad... I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459498/xcode-4-2-change-the-iphone-xib-to-ipad-xib), which showed me how to change the source code for the .xib files... it now works like a champ!